# Most compact, efficient, readable and clever solution for the "Find the first repeated character in a string" challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a programming interview tomorrow and I'm practicing for it. I read that one of the common questions is to find the first repeated character in a string, using the prototype

```
size_t FindFirstRepeatedChar ( char * );
```

The best solution I could come up with is

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

char FindFirstRepeatedChar ( char * S )
{
   /* Returns the index of the first repeated character in the string S. 
      Assume S does indeed contain a repeat.
   */
   std::vector<bool> booVec(128,false)
   for (char * c1(S), * c2(S+strlen(S)); c1 != c2; ++c1)
   {
       size_t i((size_t)*c1); 
       if (booVec[i] == false) booVec[i] = true;
       else return (char)i;
   }   
}
```

but I'm wondering

(1) Is this wrong?

(2) If it's not wrong, is there any way I can save electrons, i.e. optimize it further?

(3) Is there a standard library algorithm that I can exploit to solve it in 1 line?

Comment: 1.No it is not wrong. This is one of the famous algorithm I have studied so far.

2. I am not proficient in cpp but why is c2 for?

Comment: The compiler wouldn't let you overload a function by its returntype. The runtime would hopefully detect the undefined behaviour when invoked with an empty string or anything outside ASCII. My coding guidelines would reject your program for using a `char *` to pass a string, comparing booleans (`if(boolean == false)` instead of `if(not boolean)`), using C-style cast and using magic numbers. Finally, I would challenge the documentation of the function, which contradicts what it does. Finally, using a bitset doesn't require dynamic allocation, but you should first write solid code, then optimize.

Comment: This should probably be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Personally, I'd use std::bitset instead of std::vector<bool>. The prototype for the argument should be const char*, not char*, and you'll crash and burn if there is a character outside of the low ascii range. If you're going to use bools, use bools; !boolvec[i] is clearer then (boolvec[i] == false). Returning a `char` is dumb. (And won't work reliably.)

Comment: `booVec` is a very poor variable name, besides it referencing the type and not the content it is esthetically ugly. In an interview you should be very carefully with that kind of things because even if they seem unimportant to you (the important thing is if the code works, right?*), they are quite striking, the first thing the evaluator will notice. (*) Actually, naming is quite important, a key matter for writing maintainable software.

Answer (score 2):

Usually interviews aren't expecting you to say that this library already does it since they want to check if you can code and write an algorithm.

As to improve it, I would say in an interview they're probably not asking for the best optimization but more for something easy to read (which would also mean less risk of mistakes when you're writing it).

I would probably write a very simple nested loop within the first one. It is slower but very easy to write. I would move to your solution later if they ask me to make something faster.

The main bug you can get in that program is that you input a `char` (usually 8 bits) and your vector stores only 128 elements so it will crash if there is a non ASCII character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few flaws.

First, `char` may be signed or unsigned, and casting a `signed char` to `size_t` directly [may have unintended consequences](https://ideone.com/3gUHxx) due to sign extension. This is only interesting of course, if you accept that any characters greater than 127 might exist, which your code currently does not support at all - if this is not the case, you can reduce the size of your `vector` even further, though.

Second, you perform *two* iterations, one of which hits the whole string: `strlen` can only perform its work by running over the whole string... We can add a little more trickery here by setting the initial value of `booVec[0]` to `true`: This will trigger the `return` on the first occurrence, and thus allow us to completely remove the loop exit condition while improving safety.

Third, your code is not unicode aware, although this might be by design.

By replacing `char*`s with `char const*`s, we allow the code to work on e.g. string literals as well.

Finally, you can replace your usage of `vector` with an array. This will slightly increase runtime memory usage, but will probably increase performance significantly (due to not requiring a heap allocation and no bit-manipulation to extract bits from the bitvector).

```
char FindFirstRepeatedChar(char const* S)
{
    bool booVec[(std::numeric_limits<char>::max)()] = { true };
    for (char const* c(S); ; ++c)
    {
        size_t i(static_cast<unsigned char>(*c)); 
        if (booVec[i] == false) booVec[i] = true;
        else return *c;
    }
}
```

Finally, for the standard library: Since standard library algorithms require an end iterator, they will be less performant without additional trickery (e.g. writing an iterator type type with interesting semantics) which requires more code than your whole example.

Comment: Good point about `strlen` amounting to an additional iteration over the string. The statement `*c;` caught me off-guard at first, but I'll start using it in the future, or maybe use `*c != '\0` so I don't confuse the interviewer.

Comment: @HillaryRodhamClinton The fun thing is that you visit at most 256 characters (255 non-null characters followed by one repetition or null character) before termination this way. This means that a string of, say, 1000 elements will *always* be dealt with quicker!

Comment: Well anyway if you do write "assume that there is a duplicate" you might as well write no condition at all since you assume it will exit anyway. There isn't even a return for the case you didn't find a duplicate

Comment: @meneldal I took the OPs code as a basis and used his assumptions (he explicitly states there will be a repetition). Nevertheless, a little `return false;` at the end leads to more robust code without any real cost, as you correctly noticed ;)

Comment: You initialize the vector with true, don't you?

Comment: @PeterSchneider No, the initializer only contains a single element (that at index 0). Every other element is implicitly initialized to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of ways to use regex matching. This works, assuming there is a duplicate. `perl -pe '$_=reverse;s/(.*(.).*\2.*)/\2/s'`. It would be better if I could get rid of the reverse, though.

Answer (score 0):

I might try this:

```
char FindFirstRepeatedChar(char *S) {
    size_t i = 1;
    while (!memchr(S, S[i], i)) i++;
    return S[i];
}
```

The repeat must appear in the first 256 characters (by the pigeon-hole principle), so this code always runs in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

- What others observed already: the negative chars issue is worst because it will crash. Using vector is inefficient because it allocates memory dynamically, a usually expensive operation. Iterating the string once just for finding its end can be avoided by testing for the null char on the fly.
- My main concern is that you silently changed the function's return type from what was required/specified. That's pretty bad in this case because a user only reading the specification/documentation would assume that `FindFirstRepeatedChar` returns size_t. He could code

  ```
  size_t firstRepIndex = S[FindFirstRepeatedChar ( char * S )];
  ```

  which would not even lead to a warning because char has an integer promotion path to size_t. That "index" (in the range 1..255) can be out of range if `S` is short so that indexing `S` with it will be UB.

  Returning a char also conveys less information than an index (where is the repetition?). Lastly, an index has values for "no repetition" (0 or the one-past the last element index), if some day you may want to test unknown strings. Chars do not have an "escape value" because in the general case a char can hold any bit pattern, including 0 (although in this case, since no length parameter is present, we must assume 0 terminated string arguments so that 0 can be used to indicate "not found").

Comment: Check again, strlen() is *not* called in the loop! This part is fully correct, init the loop counter and maximum in the first section of the for-loop header, compare in the second, increment in the third. I'd call that idiomatic even.

Comment: I also corrected the result variable's type to size_t so that my complaint becomes intelligible at all. The whole point is the that user may think from the docs that the function determines an index, which it doesn't. I must have been tired.